# Writing a file using python which is getting called by ajax

Tags: php, python, html, ajax

I have to write a new file using python which is getting called in the following series:

html -> ajax -> php -> python

Sample python file:

```
import subprocess
import os

DIR="/home/name/name1/XML_OUTPUT/try1";
TEMP_VSWITCH_XML = "/home/name/name1/vswitch.xml"
SWITCH_XML = "%s/switch.xml" %DIR

SWITCH_NAME="test_switch";
SCHEMA_VERSION="V1";

def prep_xml():
    print "Switch with name %s does not exist, creating SWITCH\n" %SWITCH_NAME;
    print "Hello1";
    print "Hello2";
    os.system("/home/name/name1/XML_OUTPUT/try1/switch.xml");
    subprocess.call(" sed \"s/SWITCH_NAME/%s/g\" /home/name/name1/XML/vswitch.xml > %s" %(SWITCH_NAME, TEMP_VSWITCH_XML), shell=True)
    print "Got it";

    prep_xml();
```

Above python script is called by ajax -> php. When the python script is invoked php file name(php -f test.php), new file is generated and modified. But when the php script is called by ajax, nothing works.

Sample php file:

```
<?php

 myfunction();

function myfunction()
 {
  $command=escapeshellcmd('/usr/bin/python sea1.py $2>&1');

  $out=shell_exec($command);

  echo $out;
  }
  ?>
```

Please help me.

Comment: When you call the file from the command line and when it goes through the web server, the files get executed using different users. Make sure that the web servers user is allowed to execute the file. (which user it is depends on the web server and the OS). You can also try to set an absolute path to the `sea1.py` file.

Comment: I also don't see why you can't just do the same thing in PHP right away. I'm a big fan of Python, but it feels like a unnecessary step to run sed via python, when you can do exactly the same thing in PHP. Any reasons why you have to make this more complicated than it has to be?

Comment: I am doing complicated operation in python, I have just pasted part of code which doesn't work. 'sed' is followed by many steps, so I cannot do that in php.

Is it possible to return to php, do 'sed' and come back to python ?